# jQuery how to get data from json with multiple loop

Tags: jquery, json

I have json data like this http://pastebin.com/k3a5UNsL
[image]
When viewed using the json formater, I want to take the data stored on the object using jquery inside **possible_persons** object.

I'm trying to loop into the data, but confused how do I get the data names, gender, addresses, etc...
[image]
[image]

When I use this code

```
function build_possible_persons(result) {
    var relationship = result['possible_persons'];
    $.each(relationship, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value, function(sec_key, sec_value) {
            alert(sec_value);
        });
    });
}
```

I get a result of the alert value of the results of the first loop, which as shown in Figure 0:25, 3788825f48716e6c ...., [object], [object], etc ....

How can I do a looping into the objects in it in order to get the value I want?
I try

```
function build_possible_persons(result) {
    var relationship = result['possible_persons'];
    $.each(relationship, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value, function(sec_key, sec_value) {
            $.each(sec_key.names, function(third_key, third_value) {
                alert(third_key);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

or use

```
alert(sec_key.names[0].display);
```

But no luck. The code that I create show no results.

Please help to see the flaws in my code. Thanks

Comment: As a side remark, in an otherwise well-formed question I find the images actually distracting. Since your data is plentiful the paste is appropriate but rather than a picture of the tree I'd rather see a minified object that shows the relevant properties

Comment: I had wanted to make it easier to read the data. But all right, as input for my better future. Thank you for your help @Assimilater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that in your second loop's `sec_key` is the text `"names"` (as well as your other properties. If you want to loop over names replace with:

`$.each(value['names'], function(j, name)`

Second problem: not all of your `relationship`s have a property `names` so you need to check for this:

```
if(value['names']) {
    $.each(value['names'], function(....
```

finally each "name" is an object that has properties first and last. If you alert an object you're not going to see the actual names. You should make sure of the `display` property you have set or reconstruct the string

Bringing it all together:

```
$.each(relationship, function(i, value) {
    if (value['names'] !== undefined) {
        $.each(value['names'], function(j, name) {
            console.log(name.display);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Assimilater , how to query not only name data? I want to get all data, like `gender`, `addresses`, etc in one looping. Your sample when I tried only loop for `value['names']` object. am I rigth?

Comment: @BerthoJoris I had hoped that this would give you enough detail to help you with the rest. The way your data is formatted, `gender` is an object as opposed to an array like `addresses` and `names`. For `gender` just look at `value['gender'].content` and for `addresses` you can copy the inner loop for `names`. If this isn't enough I'd recommend a new question with more specificity on the desired output

Answer (score 2):

It could be simpler with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function build_possible_persons(result) {
    var persons = result.possible_persons;
    alert(persons.map(p => p.addresses ? p.addresses[0].display : 'N/A').join("\n"))
}
```

**EDIT:** using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you could merge the person's data like this:

```
function build_possible_persons(result) {
  var persons = result.possible_persons;
  var rows = persons.map(p => {
    var address = p.addresses ? p.addresses[0].display : 'N/A';
    var name = p.names ? p.names[0].display : 'N/A'
    return name + ' ' + address; 
  });

  alert(rows.join('\n'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help....I tried and get result.

But how do I merge the address data with other data? Eg names.
Usually if I use `$.each` I could create additional mechanisms to use `$.append` row for each row of data found. If you use the code that you created how do I get the data per one data? Thank you for your help

Comment: answer updated ;), keep in mind that `p => {` in this situation is the same that `function(p) {` and instead of `return name + ' ' + address;` you could do `$.append()`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Santiago 
Cheers... ;)

Comment: Hi @Santiago how to make return value get and looping via `$.each` ? I tried but always fail

Comment: you have to store the values in a variable out of your `$.each` and return it after `$.each` is done. Something like this: `var result = []; $.each(values, function(i, value){ result.push(value)}); return result;`